# Поиск ближайших объектов в списке

Tags: python, алгоритм

В общем, у меня есть файл со строками вида:

```
ADG,AIRPORT,USA,49221,,MI,,Madison,Adrian,,W Cadmus Rd,-84.07275,41.87428,Lenawee County Airport,

ADS,AIRPORT,USA,75001,,TX,,Addison,,4699,Airport Pky,-96.83121,32.96595,Addison Airport,

ADT,AIRPORT,USA,74820,,OK,,Ada,,,Airport Rd,-96.67693,34.80222,Ada Municipal Airport,
```

Есть функция, запрашивающая ввести широту и долготу, т.е. (-84.07275,41.87428), эти координаты - наше местоположение.
Мне нужно чтобы при вводе широты и долготы печатались аэропорты по отдалению от нас.
Всяко пробовал, не получается, может вы подскажете?

```
def search(obj1, obj2):
    for line in file_airport:
        Str_file = ''.join(line).title()
        List_file = Str_file.split(',')
        List_file2 = [List_file[12:13], List_file[11:12], List_file]
        sorted(List_file2)
        if list(obj1) < List_file2[0]:
            for count in range(1,10):
                count += 1
                print sorted(List_file2[0]), List_file2[2], '\n'
                break
```

Я пока написал то что думал для широты, но выводит не то, что нужно.

При таком виде как у меня написано выводит следующее:

```
['42.06228'] ['Aia', 'Airport', 'Usa', '69301', '', 'Ne', '', 'Box Butte', 'Alliance', '', 'Sarpy Rd', '-102.81021', '42.06228', 'Alliance Municipal Airport', '\n']

['40.11228'] ['Aid', 'Airport', 'Usa', '46017', '', 'In', '', 'Chesterfield', 'Anderson', '282', 'Airport Rd', '-85.61454', '40.11228', 'Anderson Municipal Airport', '']
```

Где и есть `List_file2[0]` - `['40.11228']`

Как я понял он может не сортировать их из-за того что например, на данный момент в цикле сравнивается `list(obj1)` с`List_file2[0]`, т.е. одну строку. Так ли это? И как это исправить?

Comment: Что такое "sorted(List_file2[0])" ? Сортировка массива из одного элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первый взгляд проблема может быть в строке

```
sorted(List_file2)
```

Попробуйте так:

```
List_file2 = sorted(List_file2)
```

или

```
List_file2.sort()
```

Функция `sorted` возвращает новый отсортированный массив, а содержимое `List_file2` не меняется. Метод `sort` списка производит изменение содержимого объекта, у которого он был вызван.

upd:
Еще не понятно вот это:

```
 for count in range(1,10):
            count += 1 # <--- зачем?
```

Если это счетчик, то он инкрементируется автоматически, а если нужно идти через два шага, то нужно писать `for count in range(1, 10, 2)`

**upd2:**
вот набросал простенький пример: http://ideone.com/wETPW

Comment: и так и так пробовал)найн!(Мне кажется дело не в этом, может я думаю не в ту сторону..(никаких идей нет((

Comment: Сорри, на Си уже думаю)Мне нужно чтобы выводило аэропорты по отдалению, 10 аэропортов

Comment: Вроде набросал как в вашем примере, только передал широту из другой фунции, выводит только 1 аэропорт, а как сделать если 2 аргумента передаем? широту и долготу? их как то объединять надо или можно в одном условии задать?

Comment: Самое простое и не правильное - рассчитать по теореме Пифагора. 

i.append( (( float(i[12]) - out_lon)**2 + float(i[12] - out_lat)**2)**0.5 )

Не правильно потому что не учитываем кривизну Земли. А вот как рассчитать с учетом, этого я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Это так делается:

```
Самый простой вариант: {
       1. Ваша точка местоположения - это начало оси координат (0,0).
       2. Аэропорты - это точки на оси, которые имеют координаты, отличные от Ваших.
       3. Расстояние до аэропорта - прямая от Вас до координаты аэропорта => мы  получаем  координаты начала и конца отрезка => Мы можем найти расстояние.
}
```

Если нужен более подробный пример - обращаемся.

P.S. Попробуй нарисовать на листике последовательность, которую я озвучил. Думаю, тогда вопрос отвалится сам по себе.

[img] http://monitoring.tracking.by/dasfas.png [/img]
Вот примерная таблица.

Таким образом ты расстояние не получишь, но получишь возможность отсортировать по отдалению.

Ваще тема определения расстояния крайне смутная и тяжеленная. 
У каждого квадрата есть твой коэффициент искривления земли. Например, в Московском - 1.3, кажется.

P.P.S. Человек, который писал про пример на питоне в ГисЛаб - он привел пример приблизительного определения местоположения. Точный должен быть с использованием коэффициентов для каждого квадрата.

Ладно, что-то я уже пошел в дебри :))

## Продолжение

Вспоминая теорему пифагора.........
Сумма квадратов катетов равна квадрату гипотенузы :)
Гепотенуза - Расстояние от аэропорта до Вас (Если, конечно, долгота, либо широта точки не равна Вашей).

```
X,Y - vмои координаты (42,354, 23,356)
X1,Y1 - координаты аэропорта. (41,31, 20,20)
Z - Расстояние (гипотенуза)
(Не забываем, я - центр оси)

X-X1 = Xо; (~1.044);
Y-Y! = Yo; (~3.156);

Xo^2 + Yo^2 = Z^2 ()
1,09 + 9,96 = 11,05
Z = 3,324; - Вот тебе коэффициент удаления аэропорта от тебя.
```

Comment: Нарисовал, как найти расстояние - не понял((или реализовать это на питоне не могу(я уже с 8 утра на работе сижу)уже башка не варит, а завтра сдавать(Если можно - поподробнее..)

Comment: счяс нарисую.... секунду.

Comment: Хех...начал считать)питоновский калькулятор насчитал не 31 а 41 каким то образом(5^2 + 4^2), а вот обратно - 5.4+(5.4^2) = 31...А что значит 31 ~ 5.4? Может вы описались?)))

Comment: P.S. Коэффициент лучше всего подсчитывать в DOUBLE с округлением до 0.000001

Answer (score 0):

Ни черта не понимаю в Питонах, но, может быть здесь:

http://gis-lab.info/qa/great-circles.html

Там имеется в гл.4. Реализация на языке Python

Comment: Да, тема хорошая, но от меня не это требуется...((спасибо! Мне не нужно вычислять расстояние, мне нужно просто вывести список аэропортов по отдаленю от наших координат)

Comment: А как вы собираетесь вычислять близлежащие аэропорты от заданной координаты, не зная расстояния между аэропортом и данной точкой?

Comment: я думал это реализовать так: сравнивать координаты аэропорта по широте и долготе с нашими, и если они близки к нашим - это и есть близлежайший аэропорт...(и сейчас начинаю понимать, что я тупой)..да и с математикой и геометрией у меня не оч...((простите..)

Comment: Блииин)парни, вы все помогаете, а я всем то не могу поставить правильный ответ, да и баллов то всего 14..не справедливо)